# How to convert Uint8ClampedArray to image without using DOM functions?

Tags: javascript, image, blob, data-conversion, clamp

**TL/DR:** How to convert `Uint8ClampedArray` with RGBA values to an image without using `DOM` (`canvas` element) or `OffscreenCanvas`?

I'm looking for a way to convert a `Uint8ClampedArray` object, which holds RGBA values, to a valid `Blob` object or a `Blob` URL using `URL.createObjectURL` for data which was created by the `blurhash`or `fast-blurhash` packages, with the restriction of not being able to use the `DOM` (`canvas`, etc.) or `OffscreenCanvas`.

The `blurhash` library converts a "blurhash" to a `Uint8ClampedArray` object, holding RGBA values, which then can be used to render a placeholder image; most often by using a `canvas` element.

In my case I'd like to create a viewable in-browser image from the `Uint8ClampedArray` object without using `DOM`-related functions or `OffscreenCanvas`.

Is there any way to convert the given `Uint8ClampedArray` data to a viewable image using `Blob`, a `Blob` URL or any other browser-native functionality without using `canvas`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The best would have been to have a way to go from an ImageBitmap to a Blob directly, but there isn't, yet (though a bitmaprenderer canvas is very close to this).

But you could write yourself a png (or any other format) encoder, or use one already available on the Internets (here I'll use https://github.com/wheany/js-png-encoder because it was already in my browser's history, for some reasons).

```js
// We use a 32bit Array because it's faster to set pixels on it
const data = new Uint32Array(300*150);
// make some noise
for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF + 0xFF000000;
}
const uint8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(data.buffer);
const as_str = [...uint8].map(byte => String.fromCharCode(byte)).join("");
const png_str = generatePng(300, 150, as_str);
const png_arr = new Uint8Array(png_str.length);
for (let i = 0; i < png_str.length; i++) {
  png_arr[i] = png_str.charCodeAt(i);
}
const blob = new Blob([png_arr], {type: "image/png"});
const img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.append(img)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/wheany/js-png-encoder@master/generatepng.js"></script>
```

However this may not be such a good idea. Just in this snippet, we did copy the image's data 5 times in memory (2 times as raw pixel data, 3 times as png), all the path we used to do all the conversions were extremely slow, compared to what native libpng can do. I don't know why you think you can't use a canvas, but note that even node [has a 2D canvas implementation](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas).